# How do I css customize the TOC which is placed in the sidebar in DokuWiki

Tags: css, templates, customization, dokuwiki, tableofcontents

I have chosen to place the table of contents in the sidebar instead of the actual article in DokuWiki. This makes the regular css-styles for customizing the TOC un-usable. I am not able to find the right css-styles as well as which css file I should be editing.

I simply want to make the TOC list without bullets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#dokuwiki__aside ul li {
  list-style: none outside none;
}
```

if that doesn't work right click the list and select inspect element to find the correct target.

Comment: That didn't work. Will try out some more though. Here is the div-tree from my browser. http://bildr.no/view/WVJXUVdG . Not sure which class I should aim that code at.

Comment: I finally managed to solve it. The template was using background attributes to add the bullets, not with list-style. Removed the background and everything worked out great.

Answer (score 2):

The Css for a bulletless list is:

```
ul
{
list-style-type: none;
}
```